# Turn Query result into hyperlink

Tags: php, html

I was wondering how can I fetch some result from a specific $row in MySQL to become a hyperlink. So, in this case, let's say I fetch a website from my search query and it's Google.com how do I make it so that when I click it's automatically Google.com. I do know that you can add a href but I don't want to have to type for each website since I'm building a directory, I would like the system to recognize right away this is a new website and turn it into a hyperlink.

Here's part of the code;

```
if ($queryResult > 0) {
    while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<table>
          <thead>
         <th>".$row['NAME']."</th>
         <th>".$row['WEBSITE']."</th>
```

Comment: `echo "<a href=\"".$row['WEBSITE']."\">".$row['WEBSITE']."</a>"`?

Comment: try to remove the unnecessary words from your question

Comment: You must write code for _the system to recognize right away this is a new website and turn it into a hyperlink_

Comment: What do you mean by ___a new website___

Comment: Will your query return 1 row or many rows? Do you really want the hyperlink in the headings of your table or in each of the rows in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Is below solution satisfies:

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM websites");

if ($result > 0) {
    echo '<table><thead><th>Name</th><th>URL</th></thead>';
         
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>
             <td>$row[NAME]</td>
             <td><a href=\"$row[WEBSITE]\">$row[WEBSITE]</a></td>
         </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Look here for working example: [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=47785bde5060ea6221993b96605b9fea&sqlses=92ab96a38aa70107af272d9ab07691e3&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Less escaping makes easier maintenance `<td><a href='$row[WEBSITE]'>$row[WEBSITE]</a></td>`